# What should I be using instead of Generics if I want to be able to create instances of them?

Tags: java, c#, oop, generics

I'm learning Java, coming from a C# background, and am a bit confused by some details of how Java implements generics.

I'm trying to implement a set of classes that represent various kinds of measurements, that work something like this (a bit simplified, but hopefully still getting the point across)

```
abstract class Measure{
  public double value;
  //used for multidimensional measures, volume, etc.
  public Measure[] children;

  public Measure(String s){
    children = new Measure[0];
    try{
      setValue(s);
    } catch (MeasureValueException E){
      setDefaultValue();
    }
  }
  
  public void setDefaultValue();
  public void setValue(String s) throws MeasureValueException;
  ...
}

class Length extends Measure{
  public Length(String s){super(s);}
  
  public setDefaultValue(){
    value = 0;
  }
  public setValue(string s) throws MeasureValueException{
    if(s.endsWith(" meters")){
      try{
        value = Double.parseDouble(s.substring(o, s.length() - 7));
      } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new MeasureValueException("Improperly formatted length: " + s);
      }
    } else {
      throw new MeasureValueException("Incorrect units for length: " + s);
    }
  }
  ...
}

class Volume extends Measure{
  public Volume(string s){super(s);}

  public void setDefaultValue(){
    value = 0;
    children = new Measure[]{new Length("0 meters"), new Length("0 meters"), new Length("0 meters")};
  }
  public void setValue(String s) throws MeasureValueException{...}
  ...
}

class Mass extends Measure{...}
```

...and so on.

I'd like to implement a class called `Range`, which represents a range of measures, and I'd like for the `Range` class itself to be a Measure, and for it to be possible to have a Range of Ranges and so on for reasons that make sense in the context of what I'm trying to do, though I appreciate that it sounds pretty strange outside of that context.

Now, generics seem like the obvious tool to use here, defining something like `Range<E extends Measure>` and containing a minimum and maximum Measure in its children, but this approach runs into problems at the `setDefaultValue()` method, which if I'm understanding correctly how generics work in Java, straight-up *can't* initialize said minimum and maximum to anything other than null. In fact, it would be impossible to ever set the minimum/maximum of a range to be anything other than null without defining special methods for it that take Measures of some kind as inputs, since otherwise it would never have access to a member of the appropriate class and so wouldn't be able to instantiate them.

I can think of a couple other, equally hideous workarounds, like defining `LengthRange`, `VolumeRange`, `MassRange` and so on, or having a `MeasureFactory` class somewhere with a bunch of string parsing logic that has to be passed to everything in the program and smears dependencies throughout everything, but it feels to me like there's something I don't know about or something I've overlooked which should be able to accomplish this, since the failure of the generic class falls on exactly that one point. Am I right in thinking this, or does Java simply not have a way to do what I'm trying to do without making things extremely messy?

Comment: `Now, generics seem like the obvious tool to use here, defining something like Range<E extends Measure>` I personally would first prefer composition for making a class ("Range has-a Measure"), then look at inheritance next.  Generics are a fairly distant third when I try to show relationships between classes.  (And yes, Java generics are peculiar.  You'll probably use them less than you would in other languages.)

Comment: Consider, instead of having setters at all, making these immutable -- not having setters at all, and requiring a `Range` to be e.g. constructed with two bounds.  You might then have factory methods per type: `zeroLengthRange()` or the like.

Comment: `like defining LengthRange, VolumeRange, MassRange and so on,` These are *NOT* hideous, if you actually need these distinct classes, and if you need them to have different behaviors.  If you really need them, there's seldom any way to take short cuts that avoid writing code.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Instead of upper and lower bounds, I would consider using a var-arg constructor and just pass in all values needed `public Measure( double... m )`.  Making this class immutable is a good idea, imo.

Comment: Some good points here. I'm not sure I can get away with making them immutable, though I can see that the reason why isn't really clear here. Var-arg constructors definitely won't work for reasons that definitely aren't clear here (long story short you'd either need different types of arg or an arbitrary number of 'type specifying' args as well as double args)

Comment: @markspace the biggest problem with `LengthRange` and the like is that every time I add a new `Measure` I now need to add a new `MeasureRange`, and elsewhere in my program I need to write twice as much new logic, first for handling the new measure, then for the new range. While it's certainly doable, I have a hard time finding it palatable to write more than twice as much code, most of it worthless boilerplate, all susceptible to errors, spread out over multiple parts of a program to get out of defining two variables.

Comment: To get help with that last point, I think you'd need to produce an example why you feel this results in unnecessary code duplication.  It isn't clear at all from what you've given us so far.

Comment: Much of that boilerplate can be avoided with appropriate abstract class skeleton work.  You shouldn't have to rewrite most of your logic more than once.

Comment: @markspace The code elsewhere I'm talking about is mostly tied up in an 'evaluator' object that, among other things, compares and combines different Measures. For example it can combine a Length with another Length to give a new Length with a value that is the sum of the original two, or a Length with a Range of Lengths to give a new Range of Lengths shifted by an amount equal to the value of the first length. The duplication would be in the `*Range` classes (which would be identical save for the `*` and the relevant parts of the evaluator object (likewise).

Comment: I'm starting to think I should perhaps give up on doing this in an OOP way and just have a single 'measure' object with an enum defining the different types... Feels like a bad thing to do in Java, but maybe this is just a thing Java was never meant to implement.

Comment: Why can't the `setDefaultValue` method in `Range<E extends Measure>` just call `setDefaultValue` on the minimum and maximum objects?  There's no reason it has to return null.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem because the minimum and maximum objects don't exist yet. Java doesn't permit instantiation of generic types, even when the existence of a relevant constructor is explicitly available.

Comment: @P... No, you can write code to instantiate them, using the type parameter that you've got.

Comment: Why do you have a *`public double value`* instance field and a *`setValue(String)`*? Is that a typo and you meant to write *`public String value`* instead? Also, in Java it's anti-idiomatic to have a setter that doesn't get passed a value (*`setDefaultValue()`*). Is that an actual idiom in C#? Speaking of which, a rough sketch of how you would implement in C# what you're after, could possibly help to get you closer to where you want to be with Java. Or is what you're after not doable in C# either? TIA.

Comment: I ran an experiment of an implementation I did based on assumptions I had to make in the absence of answers to my questions. I have established that what your question specifies is doable. It turns out it is relatively easy. The only thing *hard* about it was having to make assumptions without answers that would have clarified the use case. But again, what I have implemented is based on my *likely* incomplete interpretation of what you've specified.